# Parse through string for known section

Tags: java, string, parsing, design-patterns

I was wondering what the best way to go about parsing "HOST" names out of oracle connection strings.  Here is an example connection string:

> Data
>   Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)))

And I have it in a `String`.  What is the best way to get "MyHost" returned.  Also would be nice if it worked for double connection strings, example:

> ((Data
>   Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost1)(PORT=MyPort1)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID1))))(Data
>   Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost2)(PORT=MyPort2)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID2)))))

Would return "MyHost1" and "MyHost2".

**Trying to write a method that takes in a connection string and spits out the host/hosts in an array list of strings.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a regular expression like this should work: `\(HOST=([^)]+)\)`.

Don't forget to double the backslashes in Java `String` literals:

```
Pattern hostPattern = Pattern.compile("\\(HOST=([^)]+)\\)");
```

Create a [`Matcher`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) from that `Patttern` and your input string using [`matcher()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) and call [`find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) until it returns `false`. Use [`group(1)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) to get the host names:

```
Matcher m = hostPattern.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: How do I apply the pattern to the string so I can get the host names as a return?  Not very familiar with patterns, but I have used them before to split a string, but never to extract values.

Comment: Wouldn't a non-greedy wildcard be a bit more straightforward?  `\(HOST=(.*?)\)`  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Mark: it would be just as fine, I'm just used to this version ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Extending Joachim's idea (and I haven't used ArrayLists in a while so it may not be totally correct):

```
public List<String> getHosts(String conString) {
  List<String> conns = new ArrayList<String>()
  Pattern hostPattern = Pattern.compile("\\(HOST=([^)]+)\\)");
  Matcher m = hostPattern.matcher(conString);
  while(m.find()) {
    conns.add(m.group(1));
  }
  return conns;
}
```

EDIT: Thanks for the fixes Bart!

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression \(HOST=(.*?)\) will match the section "(HOST=MyHost1)" and "(HOST=MyHost2)" as two groups containing "MyHost1" and "MyHost2" respectively.

Cheers,

Ed